# UV decomposition

Tags: matrix-decomposition, svd

I can't understand exactly what ***UV decomposition*** is and how it can be done on a square matrix. 
So, can anyone please explain me an example of UV decomposition on any square matrix say, a 4x4 or a 5x5 matrix?

Comment: Suppose there's a Matrix A, how to decompose it into two matrices U and V such that,  A = U*V'.

Comment: V' is the transpose of the matrix V